# How to install Google WEBP on Mac OSX Mavericks via Macports

Tags: macos, macports, tiff

I run Mac OS 10.9.1 (Mavericks) and I would like to install Google's `webp` extension:

```
sudo port install webp
```

I also did a selfupdate before and an autoupdate for outdated libraries.
However, when it builds the `tiff @4.0.3` library, it builds forever (I quit after 12h)...

Any idea?

Log:

```
--->  Computing dependencies for webp
--->  Cleaning webp
--->  Scanning binaries for linking errors: 100.0%
--->  Found 7 broken file(s), matching files to ports
--->  Found 1 broken port(s), determining rebuild order
--->  Rebuilding in order
     tiff @4.0.3 
--->  Computing dependencies for tiff
--->  Cleaning tiff
--->  Scanning binaries for linking errors: 100.0%
--->  Found 7 broken file(s), matching files to ports
--->  Found 1 broken port(s), determining rebuild order
--->  Rebuilding in order
     tiff @4.0.3 
--->  Computing dependencies for tiff
--->  Fetching distfiles for tiff
--->  Verifying checksums for tiff
--->  Extracting tiff
--->  Applying patches to tiff
--->  Configuring tiff
--->  Building tiff
```

Comment: It's possible that there is a bug in the tiff portfile. For bugs in Macports portfiles file a ticket at https://trac.macports.org/.